Why does maximum likelihood estimation produce biased estimates sometimes?
I posted this question on bias of MLE's : Prove that MLE can sometimes be biased
For example, for the Normal Distribution, the $\mu$ estimate is unbiased but the $\sigma$ estimate is biased.
My question is about the following :

Why exactly does Maximum Likelihood Estimation produce biased estimates for the Normal Distribution? I mean, I can do the algebraic manipulation and see this .... I also see intuitively that the $\sigma$ estimate contains the $\mu$ estimate, and thus "brings forward the sampling uncertainty" from the first estimate, thus resulting in a bias. But is there a more mathematical reason behind this?
Looking at the formula of a Probability Distribution in general, is it possible to know in advance that MLE will provide a biased estimate?
Is there some mathematical proof that shows maximum likelihood estimation is guaranteed to produce biased estimates under certain conditions?


For the variance, this is basically the point of Bessel's correction.  After all, we know that the sample mean minimizes least square differences so, to the extent that the sample mean has some noise in it, the use of the sample  mean will give you an artificially low estimate of the true variance.
